# Magento Enterprise 1.12 - Accessing customer custom attributes from the V2 API

Tags: api, magento, soap

I've got a client that would like to use Magento's web services API to create and update customers.  Using the API we can easily manipulate the system defined attributes - firstname, lastname, etc using the V1 or V2 API. Se we're good to go there.

This is where it gets sticky - this site uses Magento Enterprise 1.12 and we have added some custom customer attributes for linking the Magento customers to their CRM data on an external system. Using the V1 API, I have full access to the custom attributes.  However, the V2 API will not expose them. Since the caller is coming from .NET, I believe he needs to use the V2 API.

Tracing the code with a debugger, I see that the V2 code gets all the attribute data and then drops all the custom data when the web service response is generated.  I tried adding the attributes to the Customer (Mage/Customer/etc/) WSDL and WSI files, but that did not do the trick.

Can anyone give me a pointer as to what I should do to expose the customer attributes?

Greg

Comment: Digging in deeper, I see now that all that you need to do to add API V2 access to the custom attributes is to add the additional fields to the customer wsdl.xml & wsi.xml files.  The new problem is that I can't figure out the correct way to override the core wsdl.  I've tried putting a modified copy at app/code/local/customer/etc/wsdl.xml, but the changes don't seem to override the wsdl in app/code/core/customer/etc/wsdl.xml.  Any thoughts?  I'm worried about modifying the wsdl in core, but I might have to do it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new module
2. In `Your_Module/etc/wsdl.xml` and `wsi.xml` add your new attribute in the same node as in the Mage_Customer `wsdl.xml` and `wsi.xml`
3. Magento merges all `wsdl.xml` and  `wsi.xml` files together

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a wsdl.xml file that I used to add customer_number to the API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
          <complexType name="customerCustomerEntity">
             <all>
               <element name="customer_number" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
             </all>
          </complexType>
       </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```